# nginx and docker hide port from url

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a droplet with nginx and docker container that works on port 4001.
I managed to implement only redirect from the main URL to my working container

```
    events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 1.1.1.1;
        port_in_redirect off;


        location / {
            return 200 'This is nginx stroke';
        }

        location ~ /cv {
            rewrite ^/cv(.*) http://1.1.1.1:4001;
        }
    }
}
```

And when url is `http://1.1.1.1/cv` me redirects to `http://1.1.1.1:4001`. How to fix it without port `:4001`

If i use

```
location /cv {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:4001;
}
```

In inspect manager  i see an empty react project, without my components:
[image]

But head is relevant

[image]

Comment: That's because you are explicitly rewrite to that string. That is not a good idea to use a rewrite in that case. I recommend you to configure it with `proxy_pass`.

Comment: @mgsxman updated a body of a question

Comment: Probably that's because of forgotten trailing slash `/` at location directive and at the end of `proxy_pass http://localhost:4001;`. Without a `/` proxy will forward traffic and rewrite to `my.site/cvsome-route` instead of `my.site/some_route`.